# создание редактора кода с подсветкой синтаксиса на JS

Tags: javascript

Я хочу сделать редактор кода (для моего языка), на JS. Если кто-то редакторы сделанные с помощью атрибута с contenteditable, пожалуйста скиньте ссылку. Конкретно меня интересует подсветка синтаксиса "на лету". Сделать подсветку по кнопке - просто, а вот чтобы сразу - проблематично.

Comment: `Ace` Вас чем не устраивает?

Comment: Так мне нужно под свой синтаксис и т.п. Я поэтому сам и пишу. Или там можно задавать подсветку на свои ключевые слова?

Comment: Ну тут тогда только самопис. Настолько специфичное решение вряд ли кто-то делал. Опять же, Вы говорите, что подсветку по кнопке сделать просто – а почему просто не отслеживать изменения и применять подсветку на лету?

Comment: Как всегда пришлось все делать самому)))

Answer (score 5):

Чтоб его, я это сделал. Только нужно еще немного с css поработать, но в целом все ок. Короче, мне надоело все и я взял textarea, сделал у него все прозрачным кроме каретки и поверх наложил div, а в нем уже рисую весь текст. Вот код:

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
const textDiv = document.getElementById('text');

const highlighterRules = [
    {class: "operator", filter: /for|if|else|=|\<|\>|\+/g},
    {class: "key_word", filter: /let|function|window/g},
    {class: "digit", filter: /\d+/g},
];

const highlighter = function (input, output) {
    let text = input.value;

    for (let i of highlighterRules) {
        text = text.replaceAll(i.filter, `<span class="${i.class}">$&</span>`);
    }

    text = text.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");

    output.innerHTML = text;
};

const adaptive = function () {
    textDiv.style.width = textarea.offsetWidth + "px";
    textDiv.style.height = textarea.offsetHeight + "px";
};

textarea.addEventListener("input", () => {
    adaptive();
    highlighter(textarea, textDiv);
});

window.onload = adaptive;
```

```css
* {
    font-family: monospace;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #6D6D69;
}

.mainContainer {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
}

.text, .textarea {
    position: absolute;
    resize: none;
}

.textarea {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    border: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    caret-color: #F8F8F2;
    outline: none;
}

.text {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #282923;
    color: #F8F8F2;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}

.operator {
    color: #F4005F;
}

.key_word {
    color: #58D1EB;
    font-style: italic;
}

.digit {
    color: #9D65FF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainContainer">
        <pre id="text" class="text"></pre>
        <textarea  id="textarea" class="textarea" contenteditable="true"></textarea> 
    </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Как видите, на длинных строках текст немного сбивается, если кто знает как это быстро исправить - прошу в комментарии. А так, надеюсь эта тема кому-то поможет. Здесь приведен пример с подсветкой (частичной) JS, но можно в highlighterRules что угодно прописать.